# How does Dynamo manage write conflict?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, riak

When Dynamo writes to a node, what will it do if this node has a conflicting version of this data?

Just drop it, or store it along with the conflicted version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specifically covered in section 4.4 (Data Versioning) of the [Dynamo paper](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/cs239-w08/decandia07dynamo.pdf); multiple versions of the object are preserved and would need to be reconciled at a later time by the client (with the follow-up of the client then writing said reconciled data back to the cluster, when talking about typical real-world usage).

We (Basho/Riak) attempt to provide fairly decent coverage of this topic as it relates to Riak, including links to additional resources, at: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/Vector-Clocks/

Comment: That paper has a lot of interesting information I was not aware of; some of it also seems incorrect with AWS's current DynamoDB offering.  Are you sure that there is a 1-to-1 relationship between Dynamo in this paper and the AWS provided DynamoDB?

Comment: @brian In section 5 of the paper, it is said that the last step of a read operation is "(v) if versioning is enabled, perform syntactic 
reconciliation and generate an opaque write context that contains 
the vector clock that subsumes all the remaining versions."  Since the coordinator is one of the nodes in dynamo so it doesn't understand the semantics of the data. My question is how can a coordinator perform syntactic reconciliation?

Comment: @CoryKendall - It's not "incorrect" re: DynamoDB, it's that DynamoDB isn't a Dynamo implementation, really :) . The OP tagged this with so many things that are very different I just went with how it works re: Dynamo (the orig paper) and Riak.